# Is Yocto SDK's character encoding affected by anything other than locale settings?

Tags: linux, bash, gnu, yocto, bitbake

As far as I know, we can modify the behavior of character encoding by manipulating the *locale* settings.
This way, if my locale settings look like following:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
...
LC_ALL=
```

and I try to run *ls* with files containing special signs (polish letters), everything works just fine:

```
[rafkamin@localhost]$ ls
żółć
```

As soon as I change my locale settings, i.e. by exporting LANG=C, special signs are replaced with question marks, because we got rid of UTF-8 encoding.

```
[rafkamin@localhost]$ ls
????????
```

**Problem**

During SDK building stage in Yocto Project, I can affect the encoding in a same way as presented above. But in the project I'm working on, although I don't explicitly modify locale settings, the character encoding is somehow affected:

```
sdk [rafkamin@...]$ touch żółć
sdk [rafkamin@...]$ ls
????????
```

However if I look into locale settings, everything seems just fine:

```
sdk [rafkamin@...]$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
...
LC_ALL=
```

At this point I'm not quite sure what I should be looking for. Is there anything that can affect character encoding in core utils, AND at the same time override whatever *locale* is pointing to?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51479976/edit) to include more information.